# Я совсем начинающий разработчик на js и у меня есть задача сделать таймер отсчета до наступления того или иного еврейского праздник

Tags: javascript

На просторах интернета я смог найти инфу как такой таймер в принципе сделать, а так же нашёл API еврейского календаря со всем функционалом

https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-js вот такой вот я нашёл API, но я никак не могу разобраться в том, как из него брать информацию и добавлять его в таймер

```
// Берём элемент для вывода таймера
let timer_show = document.getElementById("timer");
 
// Функция для вычисления разности времени
function diffSubtract(date1, date2) {
    return date2 - date1;
}
 
// Массив данных о времени
let end_date = {
    "full_year": "2020", // Год
    "month": "11", // Номер месяца
    "day": "01", // День
    "hours": "00", // Час
    "minutes": "00", // Минуты
    "seconds": "00" // Секунды
}
 
// Строка для вывода времени
let end_date_str = `${end_date.full_year}-${end_date.month}-${end_date.day}T${end_date.hours}:${end_date.minutes}:${end_date.seconds}`;

// Запуск интервала таймера
timer = setInterval(function () {
    // Получение времени сейчас
    let now = new Date();
    // Получение заданного времени
    let date = new Date(end_date_str);
    // Вычисление разницы времени 
    let ms_left = diffSubtract(now, date);
    // Если разница времени меньше или равна нулю 
    if (ms_left <= 0) { // То
        // Выключаем интервал
        clearInterval(timer);
        // Выводим сообщение об окончание
        alert("Время закончилось");
    } else { // Иначе
        // Получаем время зависимую от разницы
        let res = new Date(ms_left);
        // Делаем строку для вывода
        let str_timer = `${res.getUTCFullYear() - 1970}.${res.getUTCMonth()}.${res.getUTCDate() - 1} ${res.getUTCHours()}:${res.getUTCMinutes()}:${res.getUTCSeconds()}`;
        // Выводим время
        timer_show.innerHTML = str_timer;
    }
}, 1000)
```

ах да, ещё надо как-то разобраться как это впихнуть в wordpress, но это я думаю осилю)

Comment: проблема такого таймера, что он не будет работать в субботу :(

Comment: ну Шаббат дело отдельное :)

Comment: парни, я правда в тупике и мне бы пригодилась помощь

Comment: у вас тут все намешано в одно и евреи и праздники и таймеры, что конкретно вам надо сделать? функцию, которая будет в некотором контейнере показывать обратный отсчет до заданной даты и времени? функцию, которая рассчитывает какую-то сезонную дату от фазы луны? формирование класса, который содержит весь функционал и т.д.? т.е. что именно нужно?

Comment: нужно как раз таки первое сделать именно обратный отсчет до заданной даты, но так, чтобы после сразу пошёл отсчет до следующей

Comment: тогда задачу можно разбирать на 2 - реализация функции `setCountdown()`, которая будет создавать таймер, и `getNextPoint()`, которая будет вычислять время следующего события. Если еврейский новый год завязан на солнечный (если не путаю) цикл, то его надо будет реализовывать по особому, но самое главное - описанные выше функции будут полностью независимыми и не будут знать друг о друге